# Will this matrix have bounded orbit too?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Trying to solve:

If $A \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $Spec(A)\cap \mathbb{S}^1 = \emptyset$, then $ \exists c > 0$ such that for all non-zero $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there is $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $\|A^mx\| > c$.

One-dimensional case any constant $>0$ works. What about higher dimensions? Tried things with Jordan composition not worked. Atleast if we show for those of spectral values outside unit disc, we could apply $A^{-1}$ and get the result.

Help me with some ideas.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{S}^1$ the closed unit disk?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $\mathbb{S^1}$ is unit circle

Comment: That would mean that the question as stated is incorrect.  For example, take $A = \frac 12 I$.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof by contrapositive:**

Suppose there is an $x$ such that $S_x := \{\|A^m x\|:m \in \Bbb N\}$ is bounded.
Let $B = \{x: S_x \text{ is bounded}\}$.  We note that $B$ is not only a subspace, but an $A$-invariant subspace.

That is, we may now consider the restriction of $A$ to the space $B$, since for every $x \in B, Ax \in B$.  Let $T:B \to B$ denote this restriction.

$T$ has an eigenvalue, and that eigenvalue must have magnitude at most $1$.  Conclude that $A$ has an eigenvalue with magnitude at most $1$.

Thus, if $A$ has an eigenvalue outside the unit disk, then for all $c>0$, for all $x \neq 0$, there is a positive integer $m$ such that $\|A^m x\| > c$.

Repeating the analysis with $A^{-1}$, we can conclude that if $A$ has an eigenvalue on the interior of the unit disk, there is a *negative* integer $m$ such that $\|A^m x\| > c$.

The conclusion follows.

Comment: $T$ has a **complex** eigenvalue. I believe that it is possible to still conclude that this eigenvalue has modulus at most one, but it is not completely obvious (is it?).

Comment: I admit that this is an oversight of mine.  Off the top of my head: if $T$ has a complex eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| > 1$, then it has a $2$-dimensional invariant subspace $U$ over which $T$ acts as a scaled "rotation", so that $T^nx$ will "spiral out".

Comment: Also, it follow more simply from the fact that
$$
\|T^n\| \geq \rho(T^n) \geq |\lambda|^n
$$

Comment: Eigenvalues of absolute value less than 1 are also allowed

Comment: That runs contrary to you saying that $\Bbb S^1$ is the unit circle here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get

Comment: Spec$(1/2)I = \{1/2\}$.  $\{1/2\} \cap \Bbb S^1 = \emptyset$.

Comment: if forall constant $C > 0$ and forall $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ , $\|A^m(x)\| \leq C$, then $x = 0$. Is it happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24979/discussion-between-mambo-and-omnomnomnom).